# Trying to understand a code of counting numbers digits in python

Tags: python, function, while-loop, count, digits

Can someone explain to me the code below.
I need to understand what line 2 and line 5 mean when we count digits of a number (ex. 100).

```
def Counting(Number):
    Count = 0
    while(Number > 0):
        Number = Number // 10
        Count = Count + 1
    print("Number of Digits in a Given Number:", Count)
Counting(100)
```

Comment: You basically floor-divide the number by 10 until it is zero and add one to the count each time. So 123 becomes 12, which becomes 1, then 0, giving you a digit count of 3. Lines 2 and 5 initialize and increment that counter.

Comment: You can also take the digit count by turning the integer to a string and taking the lenght of the string like this: `digitCount = len(str(Number))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Count
```

is the variable used to store the number of digits in Number.

```
while (Number > 0):
```

this line continues looping until the Number is 0. In other words it loops while Number is a positive integer.

```
Number = Number // 10
```

floor division of Number by 10. When you divide a number by 10, you are "removing" its last digit. For example, in the case of 100, it would be

```
100 // 10 = 10
```

or in the case of 12345,

```
12345 // 10 = 1234
```

this effectively reduces the number of digits by one.

```
Count = Count + 1
```

increments Count, as we have removed one digit from Number.